# SSRS 2012 expressions

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012

I am new to the SSRS reporting building. Can you please suggest/correct my expressions for the report calculated field?

```
    IIF(((IsNothing(Parameters!AgeByDueDate.Value)),
 (IIF((Fields!adItemAgeByItemDate.Value >= 0 AND Fields!adItemAgeByItemDate.Value <= Parameters!AgeBreak1.Value),0,Fields!exCalculatedReportingOpenAmount.Value)),
 (IIF((Fields!adItemAgeByDueDate.Value >= 0 AND   Fields!adItemAgeByDueDate.Value <= Parameters!AgeBreak1.Value),0,Fields!exCalculatedReportingOpenAmount.Value ))))
```

Many thanks

Comment: What is the error that you are getting

Answer (score 0):

Bro, at least you should tell people what you're trying to do here, and whether you are getting error or just want to optimize the code.
I guess the SWITCH function will work better than IIF? If I correctly understand what you're doing with this code..... Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try using fewer parentheses, and include an `=` sign at the start of the expression - like so:

```
   =IIF( IsNothing(Parameters!AgeByDueDate.Value,
         IIF(Fields!adItemAgeByItemDate.Value >= 0 AND Fields!adItemAgeByItemDate.Value <= Parameters!AgeBreak1.Value,0,Fields!exCalculatedReportingOpenAmount.Value),
         IIF(Fields!adItemAgeByDueDate.Value >= 0 AND  Fields!adItemAgeByDueDate.Value <= Parameters!AgeBreak1.Value,0,Fields!exCalculatedReportingOpenAmount.Value) )
```

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. My input parameter, AgeBreak1 was  with dropdown list, so I had to use AgeBreak1.Value(0). This solved the issue.     Many thanks